# What is the meaning of a colon in string formatting?

Tags: python, string-formatting

In the reading of Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language),

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]  
fill        ::=  <any character>  
align       ::=  "<" | ">" | "=" | "^"  
sign        ::=  "+" | "-" | " "  
width       ::=  integer  
precision   ::=  integer  
type        ::=  "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "E" | "f" | "F" | "g" | "G" | "n" | "o" | "s" | "x" | "X" | "%"
```

the grammar really confused me.

For example, if I want to convert int to binary representation
I can do this

```
"{0:b}".format(100)
"{:b}".format(100) # but this is fine too, so what dose the 0 do?
```

I know that `b` represent the `type` part in the specification, but I can't figure out the role for `0` and `:`, what are they doing?

Comment: Refer https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are only looking at the grammar for the `format_spec`, the full grammar is specified [higher up on the same page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
arg_name          ::=  [identifier | integer]
attribute_name    ::=  identifier
element_index     ::=  integer | index_string
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
conversion        ::=  "r" | "s"
format_spec       ::=  <described in the next section>
```

In the `replacement_field` syntax notice the `:` preceding the `format_spec`.

> The `field_name` is **optionally** followed by a conversion field, which is
>   preceded by an exclamation point `'!'`, and a `format_spec`, which is
>   preceded by a colon `':'`

When the `field_name` and/or `conversion` are specified, `:` marks the end of former and the start of the `format_spec`.

In your example,

```
>>> "{0:b}".format(100)
'1100100'
```

zero specifies the optional `field_name` which in this case corresponds to the index of the item to be formatted in the passed parameter tuple; it is optional so it can be dropped.